# unable to query findOne - SpringMVC MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data, dao

I am trying to login but unable to login because findOne query fails in DAOimplementation. I put series of system.out.println to see where does things go wrong.

and I get this

```
email: abcdef Password : 123123

email2: abcdef Password2: 123123

check 1

check 2
```

for some reason program wont reach to check 3, check 4 and inside if condition where user != null.

I tried mongoTemplate, mongoOperations, using addCriteria without criteria but no luck.

## Code: UserDaoImplementation

```
import com.mthree.model.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query.query;

@Repository
@Service(value = "userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    private static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "user";

    public List<User> listUser() {
        return mongoTemplate.findAll(User.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

    public void add(User user) {
        if(!mongoTemplate.collectionExists(User.class)){
            mongoTemplate.createCollection(User.class);
        }
        user.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        mongoTemplate.insert(user, COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

    public void update(User user) {
        mongoTemplate.save(user);
    }

    public void delete(User user) {
        mongoTemplate.remove(user, COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

    public User findUserById(String id) {
        return mongoTemplate.findById(id, User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public User login(String Email, String Password) {

        System.out.println("email2: "+ Email + " Password2: "+ Password);
        try {

            System.out.println("check 1");

            Query query = new Query();

            System.out.println("check 2");

           // User user = mongoTemplate
             //       .findOne(query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("Email").is(Email)), User.class, COLLECTION_NAME);

            User user = mongoTemplate.findOne(query(where("Email").is(Email)), User.class,COLLECTION_NAME);
            System.out.println("check 3");

            if(user != null){
                //return user;
                System.out.println("check 4");

                System.out.println("password3: "+ Password + " Password4: "+ user.getPassword());
                BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
                //{} t y
                if(bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(Password, user.getPassword())) {
                    return user;
                }
            }

            return null;

        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void register(User user) {

        mongoTemplate.insert(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void changeProfile(User user) {

        mongoTemplate.save(user);
    }
}
```

## Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, HttpSession session, ModelMap modelMap){

         //simply checking the values my password is not yet encrypted
        System.out.println("email: "+ user.getEmail() + " Password : "+ user.getPassword());
        User user2 = userService.login(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
        if(user2 == null){
            modelMap.put("error", "Invalid User");
            return "account/login";
        }else{
            session.setAttribute("username", user.getFirstname());
            return "account/welcome";
        }
        //BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        //user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
       // userService.register(user);

        //return "redirect:../login";
    }
```

## User - model

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class User {

```
@Id
private String id;
private long UserId;
private String Firstname;
private String Lastname;
private String Email;
private String Password;
private String Role;
private long CountryCode;
private long MobileNumber;
private String City;
private String Address;

public User(){
    super();
}

public User(String id, long userId, String firstname, String lastname, String email, String password, String role, long countryCode, long mobileNumber, String city, String address) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.UserId = userId;
    this.Firstname = firstname;
    this.Lastname = lastname;
    this.Email = email;
    this.Password = password;
    this.Role = role;
    this.CountryCode = countryCode;
    this.MobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    this.City = city;
    this.Address = address;
}


public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getUserId() {
    return UserId;
}

public void setUserId(long userId) {
    this.UserId = userId;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return Firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.Firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return Lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.Lastname = lastname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.Email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.Password = password;
}

public String getRole() {
    return Role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.Role = role;
}

public long getCountryCode() {
    return CountryCode;
}

public void setCountryCode(long countryCode) {
    this.CountryCode = countryCode;
}

public long getMobileNumber() {
    return MobileNumber;
}

public void setMobileNumber(long mobileNumber) {
    this.MobileNumber = mobileNumber;
}

public String getCity() {
    return City;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.City = city;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.Address = address;
}

}
```

## Stack Trace

```
e: org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property email found on com.mthree.model.User!
org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property email found on com.mthree.model.User!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:257)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:230)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:205)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.getPath(QueryMapper.java:867)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.<init>(QueryMapper.java:758)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.<init>(QueryMapper.java:735)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.createPropertyField(QueryMapper.java:231)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1760)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1750)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:624)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:589)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:581)
    at com.mthree.dao.UserDaoImpl.login(UserDaoImpl.java:67)
    at com.mthree.service.UserServiceImpl.login(UserServiceImpl.java:38)
    at com.mthree.controller.HomeController.login(HomeController.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2538)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Any exception or full stack trace that you can share?

Comment: in `query(where("Email").is(Email)` `"Email"` is referring to a property and therefore should be `"email"`.

Comment: @JensSchauder no "email" did not do the trick. check my User model.

Comment: @DanielC. I have added a stacktrace have a look at it.

Comment: In your catch block you aren't printing the stack trace. Try e.printStacktrace() and post the outcome again. The Stacktrace you've added is only the log from you application starting up.

Comment: @Markus I have updated the stacktrace. it seems email is not found. I tried both "Email" and "email"

Comment: Not saying this is the cause of your current problem, but you should definitely stick to java conventions. Specifically: lower case names for fields. Spring Data (and many other libs) assume those conventions at least to some extend. When violating these conventions, things get convusing really fast.

Comment: I agree with @JensSchauder. Please use camelCase for your properties starting with a lower case letter. Seems to be the issue here.

Comment: With the stacktrace I'd actually think it IS the cause of your problem.

Comment: @JensSchauder ok, so do I update my model User to all lowercase ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proper Java (Beans) naming conventions:

CamelCase with first letter lowercase:

```
public User(String id, long userId, String firstname, String lastname, String email, String password, String role, long countryCode, long mobileNumber, String city, String address) 
{
  super();
  this.id = id;
  this.userId = userId;
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
  this.email = email;
  this.password = password;
  this.role = role;
  this.countryCode = countryCode;
  this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
  this.city = city;
  this.address = address;
}
```

Getter and Setter should be the field name with the first letter upper case and prefixed with `get` or `set` if present.

Properties referenced in queries/Strings are the same as the field name.

Note: There are some defiations from the actual Java Beans specification, e.g. the option to not have a default constructor.